# How to verify user url matches user in token in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create an object (called Post) in DRF where one of the fields is `user`, which should represent the user that created the object. I'm using Token-authentication, and I want to make sure that the request.user matches the user passed to the object. However, I'm using HyperLinkedModelSerializers so I pass the url of the user to the PostSerializer.

How do I get the url of the request.user? Do I have to create a url field in my user?

Here's the serializer classes:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    User = get_user_model()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user


class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'caption', 'video_link')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Post(**validated_data)
```

and here's the viewset

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
```

Comment: can you add the serializer class?

Comment: Just added in the parent

Comment: how do you send the ***Token*** while sending request? I couldn't find any TokenAuthentication in your view class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user logged in system, you can rewrite PostSerializer like following:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('caption', 'video_link')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        post = Post(user=self.request.user, caption=validated_data['caption'], video_link=validated_data['video_link'])
        post.save()
        return validated_data
```